# Login username AND email in Parse Android

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform

I need to implement this, I want check <strike>twice</strike> both, email and username, So, I thought if I do a normal query and check <strike>twice</strike> both, does work, but it was a error because when I tried to check password field, it's a problem.

I saw this answer from parse blog but It's not that I need. I think is possible.

[Link](https://parse.com/questions/use-username-or-email-to-sign-in-android)

Comment: Can you add the code you are trying to run? Why do you need to check the password twice?

Comment: I need to check username or email and password, because Parse just have a method to login but require username. It's very important for me, if an user wants to do login, he can do it with his email.

Comment: If you've solved the problem and one of the answers to your question helped, please mark that answer as accepted to help future visitors to SO see how to solve this same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer look like well for my question but I didn't try yet because I hadn't time to do it. As soon as possible, I will try it and if it's correct, I will mark as correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your original question, and the comments, here is what I'd suggest. It seems that you want to have a user enter an email OR username, as well as their password, to login. Your database needs both of these fields to be unique.

I'm still unclear why you are using a separate User table if you have Parse, but, let's proceed anyway assuming you are just using the Parse User object.

In Parse, you'll want to register the user the standard way

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
  ...
});
```

[Parse will automatically check that the email and username are unique](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users) for you.

Then, to login using either the username OR the email, you'll want to write a bit of a query before the login. This will swap the email for a username and then login with that username and password that the user entered.

```
// If the entered username has an @, assume it is an email
String username = "bob@example.com";

if (username.indexOf("@")) {
  ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
  query.whereEqualTo("email", username);
  query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
          if (object == null) {
              Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
          } else {
               String actualUsername = object.get("username");
               ParseUser.logInInBackground(actualusername, "showmethemoney", new LogInCallback() {
                 ...
               });
          }
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry for late answer but I had a lot of work these days. It's working!

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is not the right way of logging in using email for Parse. But I also don't think there is a right way. So the code your created is just a way to go around it, by changing the email provided into a username of that user and log in using the username that you found. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. It swaps the email for a username via a lookup.

Comment: Thanks, your response is valid for any platform

Answer (score 0):

The password will not be stored in plaintext, so you won't be able to filter on it in a query.

For logging in, you should really use one of the provided [logIn](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#logInInBackground%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods, which also handle the session for you. They only support one username (which can be an email if you wish), to which you can also add an email (via `ParseUser`'s email field).

Requiring both a username and an email begs the question: can another user then register with the same username, but a different email? I doubt that's desired, so probably best to stick to the standard approach.

Comment: I know all you said me, but username and email are UNIQUE for my app, when the user is going to register, I will check in my user table that the username doesn't exist, the same with the email. This way is so popular in a lot of apps, for example, take a look to twitter, you can not repeat your email neither your username (@...)

Do you understand? So, if you don't know the way to do it, maybe, someone knows.