# Android Parse Login with email or username

Tags: android, email, parse-platform

I'm trying to make an android app using parse that allows one to login using either their username or email. I have tried querying to get an object with a provided email address, then get that object's username to login with. However, I am getting this error:

> 'getFirstInBackground(com.parse.GetCallback)' in 'com.parse.ParseQuery' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.parse.GetCallback "com.parse.ParseObject>)'

I'm new to app dev and parse, so I'm not entirely sure what this means. From what I understand it wont let me use getFirstInBackground because that works with parseUser's and I'm working with ParseObjects, but the code I'm using I pulled from a prior stackoverflow question where this was a working answer: [Login username AND email in Parse Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157628/login-username-and-email-in-parse-android)

Here is my code:

```
            // Do this to allow for username or email log in
        if (mEmail.indexOf("@") != -1) {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("email", mEmail);
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (object == null) {
                        Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
                    } else {

                        String actualUsername = object.getString("username");
                        ParseUser.logInInBackground(actualUsername, mPassword, new LogInCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                                if (e != null) {
                                    // TODO: Show error message
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Credentials incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    // Start Intent for activity
                                    // TODO: Choose activity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#getFirstInBackground%28com.parse.GetCallback%29), the method's signature is as follows:

```
class com.parse.ParseQuery<T> {
    public void getFirstInBackground(GetCallback<T> callback)
}
```

That means that the generic type of `GetCallback` must be the same as in your `ParseQuery`. So it probably should be

```
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>()) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to query a `ParseUser` with a `GetCallBack` of type `ParseObject`.

Replace all instances of `ParseObject` with `ParseUser` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (object == null) {
                            Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
                        } else {

                            String actualUsername = user.getUsername();
                            ParseUser.logInInBackground(actualUsername, mPassword, new LogInCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e != null) {
                                        // TODO: Show error message
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Credentials incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {
                                        // Start Intent for activity
                                        // TODO: Choose activity
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
final String userOrEmal = editTextEmailOrUserName.getText().toString().trim();
final String mpassword = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (userOrEmal.contains("@")) {

                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("email", userOrEmal);
                query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                        if (object != null) {

                            ParseUser.logInInBackground(object.getString("username"), mpassword, new LogInCallback() {
                                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        Log.v("login", "secessful");
                                    } else {

                                        Log.v("login", "fail");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {

                        }


                    }
                });



            } else {
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(userOrEmal,mpassword, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {

                            Log.v("login", "secessful");
                        } else {

                            Log.v("login", "fail");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```